# Control DC circuit with an AC lock switch

Tags: switches, relay, ac, dc

I am currently adding circuit with a horn and some lights powered by a motorcycle battery. The circuit should be using about 12v 18A. What I want to do is control the circuit with a lock switch. I've found this item on ebay, http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/331822327/ignition_key_switch_lock.html and was wondering if I could use this to control my circuit.

The rating on the switch is really low, 250v 0.5A, and is rated for AC power, not DC.

1. Can I throw a relay on this switch to have to control my circuit?
2. I also would like to put a fuse on this, so what should I max my fuse at?
3. With such a low amp rating on my switch, will I even be able to trigger the relay?
4. Also, if I used this switch, what would be the worst case scenario? Could it case electric shock or an electrical fire? I don't really care if the switch gets fried, as long as nothing dangerous happens.

As a side note for relays, how much amps does it take to activate a relay? When I look at relays, I only see how much amps they are rated for.

Comment: When looking at relay specs, look for the word "coil".

Comment: thanks. I'm going to check that now. I've been reading that relays take less than 200ma to switch. I still don't know if a 500ma AC switch will be able to handle 12v 200ma of DC though.